# Reading php from an xml

Tags: php, xml

i have a datapoint xml from a url that has my api key on the end 
so it does not end in .xml but numbers.

I have been trying for the last week now to understand xml but i get confused
when theres more than one id, ideally i would like the xml below to show in php 
when used as an include, I have looked at Simple XML but again, i get confused very easily :/

I also tried this in the hope it might do what i was after, btw, i have searched
through many little scripts like this

```php
<?php
// The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('metoforecast.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('metoforecast.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open metoforecast.xml.');
}
?>
```

I edit by using a program  grab the xml, saving it with the .xml filename and the
uploading to my site, like i said, i get confused :(

I would like it to look something like this

Some bright or sunny spells then rain in the afternoon.

Today:
Some bright or sunny spells, especially in the east of the region, but with more general cloud and patchy rain spreading east in the afternoon. Maximum Temperature 12C.

Tonight:
Any rain quickly clearing early to give a dry night with some clear spells and a touch of frost in places, although cloud tending to increase again by morning. Minimum Temperature 0C.

Monday:
After a dry start, thickening cloud will bring some patchy rain from the west later. However, some brighter spells are likely in the east during the afternoon. Maximum Temperature 11C.

Outlook for Tuesday to Thursday:
Dry with some sunny spells on Tuesday. Early frost on Wednesday then dry and bright, but with rain in the west by evening. Further rain in places on Thursday.

UK forecast for the next 5 days
Cloud and rain clearing southeast today. Wet and windy tomorrow.
Today:
Cool with sunny spells and scattered showers across Scotland and Northern Ireland at first. Often cloudy elsewhere, with early rain across Wales and northwest England spreading slowly southeast and easing. Drier, brighter weather following from the northwest with winds easing.

Tonight:
A mostly dry evening, with lengthy clear spells and light winds allowing a frost to develop. Increasingly cloudy in the far west with heavy rain and strengthening winds by dawn.

Monday:
Bright but chilly to start in the east. Turning wet and windy with risk of severe gales in the north and northwest. Breezy with more patchy rain across the south.

Outlook for Tuesday to Thursday:
A chilly start on Tuesday, then largely fine and dry. Turning much more unsettled on Wednesday and Thursday with rain at times and some strengthening winds.

UK Outlook for Thursday 12 Mar 2015 to Saturday 21 Mar 2015:
It is likely that some rain will affect most parts on Thursday as a frontal system tracks its way eastwards across the UK. The rain may be heavy at times in the west with strong winds also possible. The rain may linger in the east into Friday but things should then turn more settled as high pressure is expected to develop. This leaves a lot of dry weather over the UK with some bright or sunny spells though there may well be large amounts of cloud and the odd spot of mostly light rain or drizzle. This situation looks to persist into the following week. Winds should be generally light with temperatures close to average for the time of year, although some cold nights are still likely.

UK Outlook for Sunday 22 Mar 2015 to Sunday 5 Apr 2015:
It is most probably that there will be a gradual weakening of the high pressure as we head through the latter part of March and into April. This means northern parts could well turn more unsettled, with showers or perhaps longer spells of rain. However, further south it looks like conditions are set to remain drier than average, with more spring sunshine. There is likely to be quite a large daily variation in temperatures, with warm days but chilly nights.

Updated at: 0252 on Sun 08 Mar 2015

```
<RegionalFcst xmlns="www.metoffice.gov.uk/xml/metoRegionalFcst" createdOn="2015-03-07T15:10:53" issuedAt="2015-03-07T16:00:00" regionId="ee">
<FcstPeriods>
<Period id="day1to2">
<Paragraph title="Headline:">Dry with increasing cloud. Mild although breezy.</Paragraph>
<Paragraph title="This Evening and Tonight:">
After a fine evening and clear start to the night cloud will thicken after midnight, though most parts will stay dry. Breezy winds will continue overnight. Minimum Temperature 5C.
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph title="Sunday:">
Generally cloudy with periods of rain and some brighter spells during the afternoon. Winds should ease and western parts may see a bright evening. Maximum Temperature 12C.
</Paragraph>
</Period>
<Period id="day3to5">
<Paragraph title="Outlook for Monday to Wednesday:">
Monday, a bright start but becoming windy with a spell of rain later. Tuesday should be fine with light winds. Wednesday starting fine but cloud thickening and wind strengthening later.
</Paragraph>
</Period>
<Period id="day6to15">
<Paragraph title="UK Outlook for Thursday 12 Mar 2015 to Saturday 21 Mar 2015:">
It is likely that some rain will affect most parts on Thursday as a frontal system tracks its way eastwards across the UK. The rain may be heavy at times in the west with strong winds also possible. The rain may linger in the east into Friday but things should then turn more settled as high pressure is expected to develop. This leaves a lot of dry weather over the UK with some bright or sunny spells though there may well be large amounts of cloud and the odd spot of mostly light rain or drizzle. This situation looks to persist into the following week. Winds should be generally light with temperatures close to average for the time of year, although some cold nights are still likely.
</Paragraph>
</Period>
<Period id="day16to30">
<Paragraph title="UK Outlook for Sunday 22 Mar 2015 to Sunday 5 Apr 2015:">
It is most probably that there will be a gradual weakening of the high pressure as we head through the latter part of March and into April. This means northern parts could well turn more unsettled, with showers or perhaps longer spells of rain. However, further south it looks like conditions are set to remain drier than average, with more spring sunshine. There is likely to be quite a large daily variation in temperatures, with warm days but chilly nights.
</Paragraph>
</Period>
</FcstPeriods>
</RegionalFcst>
```

Yours hopefully

Bashy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to get all `Paragraph` elements from the XML file, then simply loop over the results:

```
// Load XML. Suppress warning on namespace not being absolute
@$xml = simplexml_load_file('metoforecast.xml');

// Create prefix for namespace
$xml->registerXPathNamespace(
    "a", "www.metoffice.gov.uk/xml/metoRegionalFcst"
);

// Get all Paragraph items from the XML
$paragraphs = $xml->xpath('//a:Paragraph');

// Loop through Paragraph items, displaying title and forecast
while (list( , $paragraph) = each($paragraphs)) {
    // Begin paragraph
    echo '<p>', PHP_EOL;

    // Display title unless headline
    if ($paragraph['title'] != "Headline:")
        echo $paragraph['title'] , ' ';

    // Display forecast for the day
    echo trim($paragraph), PHP_EOL;

    // End paragraph
    echo '</p>', PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Running the above code with the XML supplied above as contents of `metoforecast.xml`, you get the following output (indented for clarity):

```
<p>
    Dry with increasing cloud. Mild although breezy.
</p>

<p>
    This Evening and Tonight: After a fine evening and clear start to the night
    cloud will thicken after midnight, though most parts will stay dry. Breezy
    winds will continue overnight. Minimum Temperature 5C.
</p>

<p>
    Sunday: Generally cloudy with periods of rain and some brighter spells
    during the afternoon. Winds should ease and western parts may see a bright
    evening. Maximum Temperature 12C.
</p>

...
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you ever so much, i have a few xml files and i now have something to work from, you are a star, again, thank you!